# What is cos(x^3) when x has a value of 2

Tags: calculus

What is cos(x^3) when x has a value of 2

I believed this to be equal to cos(8) which I understand to be 1 but this is not the right answer, can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: $\cos(2^3) = \cos(8)$ you are correct. Why do you think that $\cos(8) = 1$?

Comment: $$\cos(8^{c}) \approx -0.1455 \neq 1$$

Comment: @Nick Your calculator might have been in radians not degrees. I get .9903 approximately when my calculator is in degrees.

Comment: @PaulSundheim: The following notation is generally accepted: 
$8^{c} \equiv 8 \text{radians}$,
$8^{\circ} \equiv 8 \text{ degrees}$ and
$8^{g} \equiv 8 \text{ grads}$

Comment: @Nick Sorry, the $c$ looked like a degree sign.  I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: @PaulSundheim: It's no longer common to see since radians have been accepted as the `default` measurement of circular turns.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(8)$ is the cosine function evaluated at 8 radians.  The value is irrational and so can only be approximated.  It is not 1.

Comment: Thank you thats all they were looking for not an exact value. cos(8).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your substitution:

$[\cos(x^3)]_{x = 2} = \cos(2^3) = \cos(8)$

When we usually say $\cos(\theta)$ or $\sin(\theta)$ or any other trigonometrical function, $\theta$ is expressed in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) unless mentioned otherwise. (In the old days, $\theta^{\,c}$ denoted an angle of radian measure like how $\theta^{\, \circ}$ is known to denote an angle of degree measure)

Now, $\cos(8^c) \approx -0.1455$

But if you use $8^{\circ}$, which is $\left(8 \times \frac{\pi}{180}\right)^{c}$, then

$\cos(8^{\circ}) \approx 0.9902 \underline\approx 1$

Similarly, if you accidently set your calculator to [Gradians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian):

$\cos(8^g) \approx 0.9921 \underline\approx 1$

**Moral of the Story ::** *Radians are the default unit of angles that are stuck into trigonometric functions.*

Why? Because it's most natural.

[image: radians] [image: rads]

Note: But usually when we get values like $\cos(8)$ in problems of integration or substitution or similar, we leave it like that because we can't evaluate it by hand. (Actually, we can but it's too messy. $\cos(8)$ is much cleaner looking)